# Generate random number in delphi

Tags: delphi, random

i want to create a random number in delphi and assign it to file as a file name. I managed to do that but when i click button to generate number it always start with a 0. Any idea how to fix it

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
test:integer;

begin
test:= random(8686868686868);

edit1.Text:= inttostr(test);
end;

end.
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As user246408 said you should use `Randomize` to initialize the random number generator with a random value. Also if you want to limit the returned numbers to positive integers, use the predefined `MaxInt` constant.

The overloaded function `System.Random` that returns an `integer` has the following signature:

```
  function Random(const ARange: Integer): Integer;
```

and returns an integer `X` which satisfies the formula `0 <= X < ARange`.
To prevent a 0 value, you can add a constant of your choise, like

```
procedure TForm17.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
const
  MinRandomValue = 100000;
var
  test:integer;
begin
  test:= random(MaxInt-MinRandomValue)+MinRandomValue;
  edit1.Text:= inttostr(test);
end;
```

(MinRandomValue subtracted from MaxInt to prevent overflow)

or, you can use System.Math.RandomRange

```
test := RandomRange(100000, MaxInt);
```

Documented [here](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/System.Math.RandomRange)

Answer (score 5):

Your code has 2 problems.

1. You don't call `Randomize`, that is why you always get zero as the
   first "random" value.
2. You use too large value `8686868686868` for `Random` range, it
   exceeds 32-bit boundary and equivalent to `2444814356`.

if you need just a single "random" value use

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  test:integer;

begin
  Randomize;
  test:= random($7FFFFFFF);

  edit1.Text:= inttostr(test);
end;
```

Comment: You must not call `Randomize` more than one time inside an application.

Comment: @SirRufo Such limitation does not exist; you can call `Randomize` many times inside an application.

Comment: You should not call Randomize repeatedly. Typically once at startup suffices.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, that is more accurate than what Sir Rufo said. user246408, you probably know this but documentation says (emphasis is mine): "**Do not** combine the call to Randomize in a loop with calls to the Random function. **Typically**, Randomize is called only once, before all calls to Random." http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Randomize

Comment: `Randomize` initializes the pseudorandom generator. You call it when you need to start a new pseudorandom sequence. For example, you have class implementing an algorithm which requires a pseudorandom sequence, then the right place to call `Randomize` is the constructor. Documentation should be precise. "Typically, Randomize is called only once" was probably written in Turbo Pascal 3 times and never updated after that.

Comment: @user246408: If you call `Randomize` followed by `Random` repeatedly in quick succession, `Random` might return the same or a value that is only a few numbers apart from the previous value. That is not random. You should, as stated in the documentation, use Randomize only once or very sparingly. That text is still valid.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis - Are you sure you understand what *random* means and how it should be used? The recommendation to call `Randomize` only once is unacceptable if you need more than numbers looking like random for a human.

Comment: I know what random means and how it should be used. (Nearly) consecutive numbers are not random. The advice to use Randomize only once (or at least sparingly) is not only acceptable, it is good advice, no matter what you think of it.