# delphi generate random PIN code

Tags: delphi

I want to generate random number with specified length.

```
function _RandomCode(const CodeLen: Word): Word;
begin
  Result := Random(CodeLen);
  repeat
    Result := Result + Random(CodeLen) + 1;
  until (Length(IntToStr(Result)) = CodeLen)
end;
```

The result always `10000`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generate random number in delphi](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34481987/generate-random-number-in-delphi)

Comment: If codelen is, say, 4.  would a returned value of 0007 be acceptable? ie 7 with leading zeroes.  Or are you looking for numbers only in 1000 to 9999?

Comment: Random(4) is either 0, 1, 2, or 3. Why not simply: `Result := Random(IntPow(10, CodeLen));`?

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Simply you're brilliant. Its works as expected  i just added `Trunc` to your function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although I voted to close this question as a duplicate, on a second thought here are aspects that makes it different from a pure random function application.

First, your code doesn't give you the result you are expecting because you are *adding* small numbers (0 .. codelen-1) to the result for each loop, stopping when the value reaches a value that, when converted to string, contains the `codelen` number of characters. For a `codelen = 5` this will always stop at 10000 .. 10003. If you would have stepped through the code in the debugger, you would soon have realized why you got the result you did.

Secondly, inspired by @MichaelVincent, a PIN code usually allows leading zeros, f.ex. '0123'. I therefore assume this to be the case in this question too. Because an integer type result can not hold leading zeros, I suggest you use a `string` type result.

Call `Randomize` once only at startup of your application.

```
function _RandomCodeStr(const CodeLen: Word): string;
var
  n: integer;
begin
  SetLength(Result, CodeLen);
  for n := 1 to CodeLen do
    Result[n] := Char(ord('0')+ Random(10));
end;
```

I changed the name of the function to reflect that it returns a string.

---

Addition on request:

Regarding the `Randomize` function (or assigning `RandSeed`). It is explained in the documentation:

> Randomize initializes the built-in random number generator with a
>   random value (obtained from the system clock). The random number
>   generator should be initialized by making a call to Randomize, or by
>   assigning a value to RandSeed.
>
> Do not combine the call to Randomize in a loop with calls to the
>   Random function. Typically, Randomize is called only once, before all
>   calls to Random.

If you put the `_RandomCodeStr` function in a separate unit, you can put the call to `Randomize` in that units `initialization` section.

Comment: you picked up pretty much what I was getting at in my comment question :D

Comment: Can you please explain why should i call `Randomize` only at startup of the application rather than call it within the function itself. Because i thinking to put the function in separate unit and call it whenever i need it and get rid of calling `Randomize` on each application

Comment: @RepeatUntil I edited my answer regarding `Randomize` and how to call it once in the unit you plan to stuff it away in.

Comment: @MichaelVincent That's why I gave you credit for the inspiration ;)

Comment: I appreciate your explanation

Answer (score 3):

The reason why your code fails: You are adding small values (1..5) until the number of digits reaches 5. The reason you always gets 10000 is that you never call `Randomize` once at startup. This means that your "random" series is always the same.

Use [RandomRange](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Math.RandomRange) instead:

> Returns a random integer from a specified range.
>
> **RandomRange** returns a random integer from the range that extends between AFrom and ATo (non-inclusive). **RandomRange** can handle negative ranges (where AFrom is greater than ATo).
>
> To initialize the random number generator, add a single call Randomize or assign a value to the RandSeed variable before making any calls to **RandomRange**.

```
function _RandomCode(const CodeLen: Word): Cardinal;
// CodeLen is 1,2,3 etc.
begin 
  Result := RandomRange(0,Trunc(IntPower(10,CodeLen)));
end;
```

I assume that leading zeroes is acceptable in the PIN code, otherwise set the first parameter to a suitable value (IntPower(10,CodeLen-1)).

To convert a number with a fixed length and possible leading zeroes to a string, use:

```
Format('%.*d',[CodeLen,_RandomCode(CodeLen)])
```

Comment: `Random` returns an integer X such than 0 <= X < Range.

Comment: Some issues: `Random(intvalue)` gives integer; RandomRange doesn't include ATo, so `-1` is redundant; author definitely wants `Codelen=1,2,3,4,5`, not ten power.

Comment: CodeLen above is not CodeLen actually, better be calculated

Comment: Why not `I := Round(Power(10, CodeLen - 1)); Result := RandomRange(I, 10 * I - 1);`

Comment: because "ATo (non-inclusive)" - do not do "- 1" :-)

Comment: @Arioch'The, was the above comment meant for me?

Comment: @kobik "for everyone concerned" :-D

Comment: I fail to see how that's relevant here.

Comment: @LU RD, your edit needs to take AFrom into account. so for 5 digit CodeLen, your code might produce results of 4.

Comment: @kobik, CodeLen = 5 -> range 0 .. 99999. 5 digits, I assume leading zeroes valid for a PIN code.

Comment: @LURD the function in some calls give me result with Length-1 i mean for example `Writeln(_RandomCode(5));` = `9214`

Comment: @RepeatUntil, as explained in the answer, if you don't accept leading zeroes, set the first parameter of `RandomRange`. Since you accepted @Tom's answer, it seems you do. If you want to convert the number into a 5 digit string, use `Format('%.*d',[CodeLen,_RandomCode(CodeLen)])`.

Answer (score 1):

Two notes apart using `randomize` (but only once!!!) as pointed by Tom Brunberg

1) Random is not cryptographically-secure PRNG, thus using it to generate random (as in unpredictable) PIN-codes is rather improper idea.

2) your loop is both slow and even less secure (by calling Random many times in a row you cause its statistics to accumulate decreasing the randomness).
And it is potentially indefinite. What if one moment Length would become more than CodeLen? It will never shrink and the loop would never end; not until integer boundary wrap-around at least.

To make it somewhat better you can do it like that:

```
function _PseudoRandomCode(const CodeLen: Word): Word;
var s: string; i: integer; c: char;
begin
  SetLength(s, CodeLen); 
  for i := 1 to CodeLen do begin
    c := '0';
    Inc( c, random(10) ); // + 0..9
    s[i] := c;
  end;
  Result := StrToInt(s);
end;
```

or like that

```
function _PseudoRandomCode(const CodeLen: Word): Word;
var i,j: integer; 
begin
  i := 1; // 10^0
  for j := 1 to CodeLen do
      i := 10 * i; 
  // now i = 10^(CodeLen+1) that is '1' and CodeLen of zeroes.

  Result := Random( i );
end;
```

Though I would better make functions returning `string` value not `word` value.

```
function _PseudoRandomCode(const CodeLen: Word): String;
var s: string; i: integer; c: char;
begin
  SetLength(s, CodeLen); 
  for i := 1 to CodeLen do begin
    c := '0';
    Inc( c, random(10) ); // + 0..9
    s[i] := c;
  end;
  Result := s;
end;

function _PseudoRandomCode(const CodeLen: Word): string;
var i,j: integer; 
begin
  i := 1; // 10^0
  for j := 1 to CodeLen do
      i := 10 * i; 
  // now i = 10^(CodeLen+1) that is '1' and CodeLen of zeroes.

  Result := IntToStr(Random( i ));
  if Length(Result) < CodeLen then
    Result := StringOfChar('0', CodeLen - Length(Result)) + Result;
end;
```

What would you do when for example `_RandomCode(4) = 25` ? You would have to left-pad the PIN code with zeroes outside of that function in every place you would use it! Better to make it once inside the function.

Comment: In the second code `for j := 0 to Codelen` seems to be once too much. With `codelen=1` `i` will become 100, IOW, returned value is 0 .. 99

Comment: @TomBrunberg Correct. Fixed.